# What's the viewing order of the Queen's Blade anime?

Tags: queens-blade

I want to watch Queen's Blade but found too many titles in the franchise, so I do not know which one to watch. In what order should I watch it?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Watch them in the following order:**

- Queen's Blade - Rurou No Senshi (The Exiled Virgin)
- Queen's Blade - Gyokuza wo Tsugu Mono (Inheritor of the Throne AKA The Evil Eye)
- Queen's Blade - Gyokuza wo Tsugu Mono Specials
- Queen's Blade -  Utsukushiki Toushitachi (Beautiful Warriors)
- Queen's Blade -  Beautiful Warriors OVA
- Queen's Blade - Premium Visual Book OVA
- Vanquished Queens OVA
- Queen's Blade -  Rebellion
- Queen's Blade - Grimoire (currently airing, alternative setting to Rurou No Senshi)

If you check [MyAnimeList](http://myanimelist.net/anime/4719/Queens_Blade:_Rurou_no_Senshi), under the related section, you can see sequels, adaptations and alternative settings.

There is also a [forum](http://myanimelist.net/forum/?topicid=595217) where your question has been discussed.

[image]

Comment: can you update it please